# R In Shiny how to use input value to make an API call?

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following working app for a static call, however I would like to be able to use the input of a user to query movie reviews:

```
# Load R packages
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
library(DT)

# Declarations
NYTIMES_KEY <- "I4Lwlq8HzbpqmtFb1IkhmO6y2xW650YL"

BASE_url <- paste0("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/search.json?query=godfather&api-key=", NYTIMES_KEY)


# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
                navbarPage(
                    "Beta App",
                    tabPanel("Navbar 1",
                             sidebarPanel(
                                 tags$h3("Input:"),
                                 textInput("txt1", "Movie Name:", "")

                             ), # sidebarPanel
                             mainPanel(
                                 h1("Header 1"),

                                 h4("Output 1"),
                                 verbatimTextOutput("txtout"),
                                 dataTableOutput("tblOutput")

                             ) # mainPanel

                    )

                ) # navbarPage
) # fluidPage


# Define server function  
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$tblOutput <- renderDT(
        fromJSON(BASE_url, flatten = T) %>% data.frame() %>%
            select(results.display_title,results.link.url)
    )
} # server


# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below for a working example. Here's what I did:

- I added `library(DT)` since the original code wasn't working.
- I created a function `get_movies` that returns the movies for a given `query`.
- I created a reactive value `movies` that contains the contents of this function, and is re-evaluated when a button is clicked. I needed to add the `isolate(input$txt1)` part, because otherwise on every character that is entered, a request is sent.
- I created said button `search`.
- Since `movies` is now a [reactive](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/), we need to use it with `movies()`.

```
# Load R packages
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
library(DT)

# Declarations
NYTIMES_KEY <- "I4Lwlq8HzbpqmtFb1IkhmO6y2xW650YL"


# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
                navbarPage(
                  "Beta App",
                  tabPanel("Navbar 1",
                           sidebarPanel(
                             tags$h3("Input:"),
                             textInput("txt1", "Movie Name:", ""),
                             actionButton("search", "Search")

                           ), # sidebarPanel
                           mainPanel(
                             h1("Header 1"),

                             h4("Output 1"),
                             verbatimTextOutput("txtout"),
                             dataTableOutput("tblOutput")

                           ) # mainPanel

                  )

                ) # navbarPage
) # fluidPage


get_movies <- function(query) {
  url <- paste0("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/search.json?query=", query, "&api-key=", NYTIMES_KEY)

  fromJSON(url, flatten = T) %>% data.frame() %>%
    select(results.display_title,results.link.url)
}


# Define server function  
server <- function(input, output) {

  movies <- reactive({
    input$search

    query <- isolate(input$txt1)

    get_movies(query)
  })

  output$tblOutput <- renderDT(movies())


} # server


# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: AMAZING, THANKS! @Bas (I had edited and added the library DT but I guess you were in the middle of answering the question by then)